# Symfony Migration - forgot to add nullable to some fields

Tags: doctrine-orm, migration

After setting up and running my migration I realized I messed up and forgot to add nullable to 4 of my fields.

**Ran**

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="float")
*/
private $widgets;
```

**Suppose to be**

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
*/
private $widgets;
```

What's the recommended way to fix this?  Manually change the migration and force it to run again? Not even sure I can do that. Or should I create another migration for it and run it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have some data in the DB or not. If yes - then do it manually(from MySQL console and edit your current migration) or create another migration and run it, because dropping the migration will remove your data from these columns. If no - then you can drop, remove the current migration, and create a new migration with the nullable option.